# Displaying clickable pie charts in android app

Tags: android

Can any one please tell me is it possible to display pie chart in our application.
Do we need to use any third party api. I want to display pie chart with click event to each slice in the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this can helps: [GraphView](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html)
Is a library to create charts on Android. On the same page you can find code examples. Source code [here](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)

Other option is: [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Related questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your advise. Can we develop clickable pie charts with achartengine. Does it has classes to support clickevents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AChartEngine for clickable pie charts.
An example showing this usage can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/PieChartBuilder.java).